# Android ScrollTo View

Tags: android, layout, scroll

I have a Layout where there is a **EditText** at 75% position from top of the view and when it gets focused the keyboard is shown and the EditText automatically moves up. I want to ask what this behaviour is called and how can I reproduce this by code even without it's focused? Is there a way to do that without using ScrollView?

**UPDATED**

What I want is to show name suggestions as user types in EditText. As this is EditText, the keyboard would be shown and EditText has to be at x=0 and y=0 to have enough space for suggestions ListView so user can pick one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public void scrollTo (int x, int y)

also see smoothscroll

Comment: you mean scrollTo of ScrollView?

Comment: I used RelativeLayout's scrollTo function